# jQuery is not working in wordpress website

Tags: jquery

I'have a wordpress website using a " lightbox " gallery. It's not working properly. when we click on a Image it shows in lightbox. but the X / Close button is not working.

I have tried to make it work with this code, but not sure why it's not working.

here is the website url : http://www.mgrimmond.co.uk/gallery/

here is the code :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery(".envirabox-close").click(function(){
         jQuery("#envirabox-container-1").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Looking forward to your responses.

Kind Regards.

Comment: You need to bind the close button after popup opened, there is no issue regarding jQuery, it working well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution.

Since your HTML code is getting generated dynamically, so click will not work directly. You need to `delegate` the click event from document to the target.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("document").delegate(".envirabox-close", "click", function(){
     jQuery("#envirabox-container-1").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

You can use `on` method as well

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("document").on("click", ".envirabox-close", function(){
     jQuery("#envirabox-container-1").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you replying. Code didn't work not sure why.